# Using method of a class within the __init__() method of that class

Tags: python, button, kivy, tic-tac-toe

So I'm trying to build a small game of tic tac toe and I'm using kivy to make it happen. The problem I run into is I have made a grid of  9 buttons (3x3) and now I am binding them (or trying to).

I do all of this within the `__init__` method of my class BoardGrid since this should happen only when the program runs the first time.

```
class BoardGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoardGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.board = []
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(9):
            self.board.append('')
            self.buttons.append(Button(text=self.board[i]))
            self.buttons[i].bind(on_press=BoardGrid.callback(????, i))
            self.add_widget(self.buttons[i])

    def callback(self, btn):
        print(btn)
```

The problem is that the on_press takes a function that it will direct to and this works fine if I let BoardGrid.callback take no arguments, but since I want it to know which button was pressed I want to send in i. This leads to a problem where I need to also pass a BoardGrid into the callback function which I havnt created within the class?

Maybe I'm attacking this from the wrong angle here, I thought I could bind my buttons to a specific input in the callback funciton but that might not be possible.

Any advice on how to get the bindings to work would be much appreciated

EDIT: Seems to be working now, sorry I couldnt reply to everyone, it's my first post and I can't quite seem to understand it yet hehe. Thanks very much for the replies!

Comment: First, you have a `BoardGrid` instance, `self`. If any instance is appropriate, it's probably that one. Second, this callback might not actually need to be a method of `BoardGrid`. If it's less confusing to you to use a module-level function, go for it. Third, `BoardGrid.callback(...)` isn't a callback no matter what goes in the `...`; that's saying to run `BoardGrid.callback` immediately, not pass it as a callback. You need `functools.partial`.

Comment: Seems you need another class, say, Button, and create an array of 9 buttons in __init__.

Comment: `self.buttons[i].bind(on_press=lambda i=i: self.callback(i))` might work, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: @Robᵩ I think the `i=i` adds confusion and `partial` is better here.

Comment: So when you said works Rob, but just as I replied to below to another person its giving me btn not as an integer as I would expect but as a button object

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import partial

class BoardGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
            self.buttons[i].bind(on_press=partial(self.callback, i))
            ...

    def callback(self, btn):
        print(btn)
```

Comment: You should really elaborate on why this is the answer.